# Run Tensorflow Lite model with CMSampleBuffer from Camera without copying it

Tags: ios, tensorflow, avfoundation, tensorflow-lite, google-mlkit

I'm the author of a very popular Camera library for mobile apps (React Native / [VisionCamera](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera)) and I'm trying to add a TensorFlow Lite integration to the Camera.

This should be as generic as possible and will allow the user to drop in any `.tflite` model which just gets called with the Camera frame (`CMSampleBuffer` on iOS, `android.media.Image` on Android) and returns *any* data (output tensors).

I started with implementing the iOS part in Objective-C and set up my TensorFlow code like this:

```
NSString* modelPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"model"
                                                      ofType:@"tflite"];
NSError* error;
TFLInterpreter* interpreter = [[TFLInterpreter alloc] initWithModelPath:modelPath
                                                            error:&error];
if (error != nil) { /** ... */ }

[interpreter allocateTensorsWithError:&error];
if (error != nil) { /** ... */ }
```

And then I have my Camera Frame Callback which gets called for every Frame the Camera "sees" (60 times a second at 60 FPS):

```
auto imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(frame.buffer);
auto bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);
auto height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);
auto sourceBuffer = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);
auto inputData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:sourceBuffer length:bytesPerRow * height];

NSError* error;

TFLTensor *inputTensor = [interpreter inputTensorAtIndex:0 error:&error];
if (error != nil) { /** ... */ }

[inputTensor copyData:inputData error:&error];
if (error != nil) { /** ... */ }

[interpreter invokeWithError:&error];
if (error != nil) { /** ... */ }

TFLTensor *outputTensor = [interpreter outputTensorAtIndex:0 error:&error];
if (error != nil) { /** ... */ }

NSData *outputData = [outputTensor dataWithError:&error];
if (error != nil) { /** ... */ }

// TODO: return output data to user
```

Now I have two problems:

1. The Frame is any arbitrary size, but the models are trained to specific sizes. So I'm obviously getting the following error:

   ```
   Input tensor at index (9142529056) expects data size (110592), but got (8355840).
   ```

   I want to avoid Frame resizing here and ideally have the `TFLInterpreter` accept the Frame (`CMSampleBuffer`) *as is* and do a stride/offset/jumps internally - is that even possible? If not, how can I figure out what Frame size I need to downscale to?
2. The `TFLInterpreter` can only be invoked with `NSData`, and my Frame is a `CMSampleBuffer` allocated on the GPU. Is there any way to avoid this GPU -> CPU copy and stay on the GPU buffer the whole time? I have safe read access to that buffer in this callback.

I've seen some MLKit samples (e.g. [MLKit Object Detection iOS](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/object-detection/ios)) and they allow you to just pass the `CMSampleBuffer` to the model - I'm wondering how this will be handled internally as it seems like the library is quite performant.

Also I found [this code on GitHub](https://github.com/kunass2/naildetector/blob/7ebfb2a3b7eaf6142be3d0a85e870bad4ce29d05/DeeplabModel.mm#L121-L205) which seemed quite interesting, but I couldn't figure out where `ProcessInputWithFloatModel(..)` is from...

As you can probably tell, I'm not an expert in this field but I'd appreciate any help here. Thanks!